# Understanding Abstract Types

Tags: haskell

Looking at [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch10.html), I see:

```
data STM a -- abstract
instance Monad STM -- among other things

atomically :: STM a -> IO a

data TVar a -- abstract
newTVar   :: a -> STM (TVar a)
readTVar  :: TVar a -> STM a
writeTVar :: TVar a -> a -> STM ()
```

What's the meaning of the `abstract` in `STM` and `TVar`?

Comment: I think this is simply some comment by the author that you should implement the `STM` etc yourself. the `abstract` parts are in comment.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that you _should_ implement them yourself? I doubt it. If anything, I'd reckon it means you _can't_ implement them yourself, without access to built-in magic. Concretely, it's just saying that, just because no constructors are given in the source, the reader should not think that these types are uninhabited.

Comment: @leftaroundabout And I have yet a third opinion. It may be the case that `STM` and `TVar` can't be implemented without built-in magic, but that's not what "abstract" means. `Map` is abstract, too, but implemented in pure Haskell.

Comment: When you say "built-in magic," what does that mean - using C library, code that's quite difficult to get right, etc?

Comment: @KevinMeredith I mean types like `IO` – in GHC, this is implemented as a state monad over [`RealWorld`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.1.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#t:RealWorld), and that's what the documentation calls “deeply magical”. I.e. you literally couldn't implement this type if the `base` library didn't already supply it. (Although you can implement [something that mimicks the interface of `IO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pure-io-0.2.0/docs/PureIO.html#g:2).)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An abstract data type is one which does not expose its implementation; only the type and some operations producing and consuming that type are provided, but the constructors themselves are not available for your use.

This is usually done for one or both of these reasons:

1. There is some invariant about which values of that type are valid which the type system is not up to guaranteeing, and which must be guaranteed instead by careful programming. If each operation offered preserves them, then only the library author need be careful and users of the library may be carefree.
2. The representation of the data may be in flux. If the type is abstract, then future versions of the library can freely change how the type is implemented without fear of breaking existing programs, so long as the new representation can still support the existing construction and destruction operations.